# Android InputMethodService Inconsistent State in Fullscreen Mode

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, soft-keyboard

I am developing a soft keyboard. I have a class `MyIME` that extends `InputMethodService`.

I override `onKey(int, int)` to handle keypresses. My keyboard is able to insert and delete text the way I defined it **just fine** in portrait modes, I am just running into a problem in landscape when the keyboard is set to full screen.

In full screen mode, the framework's default `ExtractEditLayout` is used which contains an `ExtractEditText` instance. As I type in full screen mode, the following weird behavior happens:

- I can type normal characters just fine. I insert these using `getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(String.valueOf(code), 1);`
- When I press backspace to delete a character, the cursor moves back and the preceding character is removed. This behaves fine. Subsequent key strokes from this point on are no longer functioning as they are supposed to:

  - If I press backspace after the first one, the cursor moves backwards however the character does not get deleted. When backspace is pressed, `getCurrentInputConnection().deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);` is executed.
  - Similarly, if I add more characters after pressing backspace once, the cursor will move forward but the characters will not appear on the screen.

When I exit full screen mode by rotating my device back into portrait orientation, all of the characters that I typed or deleted are there. It appears as if the `ExtractEditLayout` used for composing fullscreen messages becomes out of sync with my `InputMethodService` subclass **and** it appears that they only become out of sync after I initially attempt to delete a character.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was related to an expensive `ExtractedTextRequest` I was making each time I pressed backspace. The request was being used to determine if the text field was empty so I could determine whether or not to set the keyboard into a shifted state.

I got rid of the `ExtractedTextRequest` and now determine if the textfield is empty by a two (largish) calls to `InputConnection`'s `getTextBeforeCursor()` and `getTextAfterCursor()` and the undesired behavior I described in the question component of this post no longer occurs.